# What's the name of this striped eggplant cultivar?

Tags: identification, eggplant, cultivar

I've found names like "Striped eggplant" or "Rosa Bianca".

In Spanish it's called "Berenjena listada". In Catalan it's similar: "Alberginia llistada".

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the same as "Rosa Bianca".

In English, it is called **"Listada De Gandia"**.

[Here](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/hs1242) is University of Florida's overview of common eggplant cultivars in Florida, and one can find "Listada De Gandia" among them (and also "Rosa Bianca" for that matter).

A couple of excerpts:

...

> *Listada De Gandia*: Plants grow 24–30 inches tall and 12–18 inches in
>   diameter. Plants bear 5- to 6-inch-long fruit that is a purple color
>   and has irregular white stripes.

...

> *Rosa Bianca*: Plants are similar to ‘Listada de Gandia’ with a creamy
>   white color and pink-purple irregular stripes that radiate from the
>   top

...

The cultivar has spanish origin and it is not unusual for such cultivars to keep the original name (as it is in original language).

Take a look at [this](https://www.rareseeds.com/listada-de-gandia-eggplant/) link too.

BTW, a very nice eggplant!

Comment: Thanks a lot! And then how about the small round eggplants (2 inches or 5 centimeters in diameter) that have the same colors and stripes? For example [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Eggplant_scab_2017_M3.jpg/800px-Eggplant_scab_2017_M3.jpg). If it's another cultivar, then I can open a new question for it.

Comment: Not a problem, @Fructibus. For another cultivar, just open a new question, that is the practice on this site, so that the questions are not indefinitely expanded.